# How to create seek bar using material design in android in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, material-design, seekbar

I am developing an android application.How I am implement seek bar using material design in android eclipse ?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "DiscreteSeekBar" from below url:

https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar

Thanks.

Comment: Thank's for answer i will check